# Interpreting UFW log - Brother printer and 239.255.255.250

Tags: ufw

I'm using UFW and don't know what's going on here. My ufw log has many statements like this:

```
 [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa:9c:30:5b:c3:df:c2:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.49 DST=239.255.255.250 LEN=32 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x40 TTL=1 ID=299 PROTO=2
```

- The SRC IP is my Brother printer connected by wireless to my LAN.
- I have read that the DST IP is the IP in the SSDP protocol for general service discovery?
- OUT I understand is a mixup of MAC addresses -- I suspect I need not unravel it for this question, that somewhere in there is my printer's MAC
- IN is my network device

So my inexperienced interpretation is that this is my printer calling in to my PC looking for a service and UFW is blocking it. **But I have no problem printing.**

- What's going on?
- Is it advised to configure ufw to accept this?